# IE Tab 2 vs IE Tab Plus

Tags: linux, sharepoint, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2007

I'm wonder what the differences are, especially as it pertains to SharePoint. Why should I pick one over the other or does it matter? Also are there any Linux browser solutions for SharePoint, besides Wine + IE 6.

Comment: PlayOnLinux will automatically install IE6 (IE7 as well I think) under wine for you.  It is pain free, just double click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend IE Tab 2. It has both Chrome and Firefox support and is closer to the original project as IE Tab Plus had it's core DLL rewritten. On the other hand IE Tab Plus appears to have better support and a larger user base.

Answer (score 1):

As of November 17 the Tab Plus update refuses to accept "Basic" (without its adware option) and keeps popping up a grey box whenever FF opens.  I've uninstalled it and opted for Tab 2, which seems to work the same and doesn't have the adware.  Can't vouch for it quite yet, but Tab Plus is completely unacceptable as of today.